# Powershell - word.application stop working in scripts

Tags: powershell, ms-word

```
Write-Output "$Server"    
write-output "$username"
    Copy-Item $Server -Destination "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\" -Force
    Test-path -path "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\$username.htm" -PathType Leaf
    
    Try 
    {
        $MSWord = New-Object -com word.application
        $EmailOptions = $MSWord.EmailOptions
        $EmailSignature = $EmailOptions.EmailSignature 
        $EmailSignature.NewMessageSignature='$Username'
        $EmailSignature.ReplyMessageSignature='$Username'
        $MSWord.Quit()
    } 
    Catch {
            Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
            [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("A mistake has appears")
            Exit
          } 
    Finally {
            Clear-variable -Name "Name"
            Clear-variable -Name "Username"
            }
```

Hi ! That code was working just fine last week. But now, can't change the Outlook's setting with it. I can confirm the outputs give the right variables, and the test-path is true. The "Server" variable is were the file .htm is, with the variable "Username" to find the good .htm, and then copy it in the profile. Then, test if the file is in the Outlook profile of the user. Like I say, everything here give True for the test. But the script can't then install the .htm as a default signature. I change nothing, everything was working fine until now.

Any idea what could have happen. The file copy in the good folder, but the script always got stuck in the word.application part.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Take off the single-quotes surrounding `$Username`. Because of these the variable doesn't get expanded.

Comment: Done that, and don't work. Thanks for the try.

Comment: The user running the script should have opened Word and Outlook at least once before this can work and if the single quotes were always there, this could never have worked 'fine' as you claim, because no user has a username `$Username` (literally).

Comment: Add them by mistake earlier. Continue to make test. Work when I close Outlook... That's wierd, worked before even with Outlook open.

Comment: Where and when do you run the code? Is it run on the server side from a service or web application?

Comment: For now, directly from the computer. Later, an application calling the code from a server.